# Compile cairo with freetype

Tags: c++, compilation, cairo, freetype

How to compile cairo with freetype library support?
I tried the below code

```
FT_Library library;
FT_Face face;
FT_Init_FreeType(&library);
FT_New_Face(library, "C:\\User\\admin\\Documents\\Visual Studio 
2015\\Projects\\Cairo\\Debug\\sansation.ttf", 0, &face);
cairo_font_face_t *cairo_ft_font_face_create_for_ft_face(FT_Face face,  int load_flags);
cairo_font_face_t *myfont_face
myfont_face = cairo_ft_font_face_create_for_ft_face(face,0);
```

`cairo_t* cairo = cairo_create(surface);`
  `cairo_set_font_face(cairo,myfont_face);`

I'm getting a compiler error in header file cairo-ft.h

> error :cairo was not compiled with support for the freetype font
>   backend.

Comment: did you add the `#include "cairo-platform.h"` ?

Comment: @saygins, I used the precompiled libraries from [here](https://github.com/tordex/cairo) 
`"cairo-platform.h"` is not available here. How to compile cairo with freetype library support?

Comment: you got the error because of [`CAIRO_HAS_FT_FONT`](https://github.com/tordex/cairo/blob/a48bfc3091a1ca6cef7d8b26780d3e7bdda351e8/src/cairo-ft.h#L115) is not defined. I think you should define `CAIRO_HAS_FT_FONT` in [here](https://github.com/tordex/cairo/blob/a48bfc3091a1ca6cef7d8b26780d3e7bdda351e8/src/cairo-ft-font.c#L123-L136) then compile the source codes.